# Removing text between parentheses with unmatched pairs

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to remove characters/numbers between parentheses.  Firstly, the numbered parentheses  - i.e. ("(3)") - at the start, and then anything in the second pair of parentheses.  Sometimes this second pair of parentheses has an unmatched bracket which complicates things.  An example:

```
library(qdapRegex)
n <- c("(1) Apple (Pe(ar)", "(2) Apple (Or(ang)e)", "(3) Banana (Hot(dog)")
c <- rm_between(n,"(",")", extract = TRUE)
```

To ideally get:

```
c
> "Apple" "Apple" "Banana"
```

Comment: @Sotos got me to where I need! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you always need the second word. If that is the case then here are a couple of (straightforward) ways of doing it,

```
#Base R
sapply(strsplit(n, ' '), `[`, 2)
[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Banana"

#The always fun, word() from stringr package
stringr::word(n, 2)
[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Banana"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, then you could use a replace regex with empty string like this:

```
[^A-Za-z ]
```

Or with insensitive flag

```
(?i)[^a-z ]
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UcdC3J/1)**